# Seed urls to crawl whole Youtube

Tags: youtube, web-crawler, nutch

I'm trying to crawl whole youtube.com using Apache Nutch. The problem is I need significant amount of seed urls to make sure almost all urls of Youtube get crawled. But I couldn't find any sitemap or list of urls for youtube. For example, to crawl `apple.com`, I can provide the urls of Apple website's stiemap as seeds - http://www.apple.com/sitemap.xml

Currently my only seed is - `https://www.youtube.com`.
And my `regex-urlfilter.txt` contains -

```
+^https://www.youtube.com/?(watch\\?([^#\\&\\?]*).*)?$
```

I tried good search like `filetype:xml site:youtube.com` but nothing appeared.

Can anyone help me finding a way to get a collection of seeds to crawl youtube.com?

Comment: "crawl whole youtube.com" - The number of videos on youtube is in billions. A polite crawler which fetches on page per second will download 30 millions per year. It will take 30 years to crawl the first billion. In case you really mean "whole" and not a large multi-million sample, the best way is to contact youtube.com, ask for permission and how to get a comprehensive list of URLs

Comment: Hi @SebastianNagel I understood your point. Now can you please take a look at this pull request https://github.com/apache/nutch/pull/184 I've sent ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sitemap I got : https://www.youtube.com/yt/sitemap.xml

from robots.txt. Try to follow the outgoing links from one home page to the other

and do it iteratively.